# how to properly export component containing multiple classes in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux

I'm actually working on a small react app, I actually want to connect my component to firebase, but this component contains multiple classes and multiple exports, so when i apply my method (which is based on one class component) it rendering me nothing, it supposed to returns data from firestore.

when i try to console log the state on mapStateToProps it returns **undefined** :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   console.log("state firebase",state);
   return {
     animationsfb: state.firestore.ordered.animations,
   }
}
```

that's my component that contains multiple classes:

```
export class AnimationScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
         <View>
          .........
         </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log("state firebase",state);
 return {
   animationsfb: state.firestore.ordered.animations,
 }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
           <View>
             .........
           </View>
        );
     }
}

const Navigator = FluidNavigator({

        home: {screen: AnimationScreen},
        homeDetails: {screen: DetailsScreen},
},
);

class HomeTransitions extends React.Component {
    static router = Navigator.router;


    render() {
        const {navigation} = this.props;

        return (
            <Navigator navigation={navigation}/>
        );
    }
}
// it was like this before i change it: **export default HomeTransitions**

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps), firestoreConnect([{ collection: 'animations'}])
    ) (HomeTransitions);
```

I expect to return me data on state when i console log it, but it returns undefined.

Comment: Why not just separate out the classes to their own files and export them individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are trying to connect everything to the store, including the navigator, which is probably not what you want to do.

If you are just using `animationsfb` in `AnimationScreen`, just connect this component to the store and use the output as a screen in your navigator:

```js
class AnimationScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        // [...]
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log("state firebase", state);
  return {
    animationsfb: state.firestore.ordered.animations,
  }
}

const AnimationScreenConnected = connect(mapStateToProps)(AnimationScreen);
```

Then in your navigator:

```js
const Navigator = FluidNavigator({
  home: { screen: AnimationScreenConnected },
  homeDetails: { screen: DetailsScreen },
});
```

Comment: That's actually right, now it returns the state of mapStateToProps, but the value **animationsfb** returns undefined !

Comment: `this.props.animationsfb` should be available in `AnimationScreen`, but there is probably a small delay during which it has not been fetched yet from the store. You can add a condition in your render function and displays a loading indicator if the value is not defined.

Comment: thanks for replying, actually i figure out what i'm missing, i just need to connect my component to the firebase collection, so i add this : `const AnimationScreenConnected = compose(
   connect(mapStateToProps),
   firestoreConnect( [ { collection: 'animations'} ] ))(AnimationScreen);`